# JFrog Artifactory Community Edition for C and C++ and JFrog Container Registry as a service at the same ubuntu machine

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-container-registry, jfrog-insights

I already have a Jfrog container registry instance running as a service in my machine.

The problem is, now, I need a conan repo, which JFrog Artifactory Community Edition for C and C++ can help. But I am having porblems having both running as services, since their share to many ports and service name are the same, etc...

If anyone has done it already and can help would be amazing.

Thanks in advance!